# DropDownList Flex 4.5 not working

Tags: drop-down-menu, flex4.5

I have seen a couple other posts on this but never really saw anyone point out what could be causing it and what the solution could be.

I have a loginview and I have a data model and presentation model that get injected by parsley.

The dropdown list all the sudden stopped "working". The list is bound to some data in the DM. You can click the list but the dropdown never happens and I don't get any errors at all. It just doesn't show up.

The app is an AIR application and the LoginView is in the main window if that makes any difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                      xmlns:view="com.guhsd.academicnotifier.icon.view.*"
                      creationComplete="onCreationComplete( event )"
                      alpha="0">


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.filters.DropShadowFilter;
            import com.greensock.TweenMax;
            import com.greensock.easing.Quad;
            import com.guhsd.academicnotifier.events.LoginEvent;
            import com.guhsd.academicnotifier.login.model.LoginDM;

            import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Inject]
            public var pm : LoginPM;
            [Inject]
            [Bindable]
            public var dm : LoginDM;
            [Bindable]
            public var fieldsValid : Boolean;

            [MessageHandler(selector="isloggedin")]
            public function loggedinHandler( e : Event ) : void
            {
                TweenMax.to( this, 1, { autoAlpha:0 } );
            }

            private function onCreationComplete( event : FlexEvent ) : void
            {
                setTimeout( checkLoginKey, 500 );

            }

            private function showOrHide( show : Boolean ) : void
            {
                var alpha_value : int;
                var scaleXY : int = 1;
                var newVertical : Number = 0;
                if (show)
                {

                    alpha_value = 1;
                }
                else
                {

                }

                TweenMax.to( this, 0.25, { autoAlpha:alpha_value, verticalCenter:newVertical, ease:Quad.easeOut } );
            }

            private function checkLoginKey() : void
            {
                var loginEvent : LoginEvent = new LoginEvent( LoginEvent.CHECK_LOGIN_KEY );
                dispatchEvent( loginEvent );

                setTimeout( function() : void
                {
                    BindingUtils.bindSetter( showOrHide, dm, "showview" );
                    BindingUtils.bindSetter( setDefaultSchoolSelection, dm, "lastSelectedSchool" );
                }, 2000 );
            }

            private function setDefaultSchoolSelection( schoolName : String ) : void
            {
                if (schoolName != null)
                {
                    for (var i: String in cb_schoollist.dataProvider)
                    {
                        var name : String = cb_schoollist.dataProvider.getItemAt( int( i ) ).Name;

                        if (schoolName == name)
                            cb_schoollist.selectedIndex = int( i );
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Metadata>
        [Event(name="checkLoginKey", type="com.guhsd.academicnotifier.events.LoginEvent")]
        [ManagedEvents("checkLoginKey")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <s:Rect top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
            topRightRadiusX="50" topRightRadiusY="50">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient>
                <s:GradientEntry color="#667178"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="#8C9BA5"/>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:VGroup horizontalCenter="0" verticalAlign="middle" gap="0"
              paddingTop="20"
              paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="50"
              width="100%">
        <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" paddingLeft="40">
            <s:Label text="Academic and Disipline Referrals"
                     color="#FF9900" fontSize="20"/>
            <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>
            <s:Label color="#cb0000" text="{dm.error_message}"
                     width="250"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup width="100%" paddingRight="100" paddingTop="10">
            <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>
            <s:Form id="form">

                <s:FormItem label="Username">
                    <s:TextInput id="tx_username" width="200"
                                 text="{dm.user_name}"
                                 enter="pm.login( tx_username.text, tx_password.text, cb_schoollist.selectedItem.Name );"/>
                </s:FormItem>
                <s:FormItem label="Password"
                            requiredIndicatorSource="">
                    <!-- sf88fd -->
                    <s:TextInput id="tx_password" width="200"
                                 text="" enter="pm.login( tx_username.text, tx_password.text, cb_schoollist.selectedItem.Name );"
                                 displayAsPassword="true"/>
                </s:FormItem>
                <s:FormItem label="School">
                    <s:DropDownList id="cb_schoollist"
                                dataProvider="{dm.school_list}"
                                labelField="Name"
                                selectedIndex="0" width="100%"
                                close="pm.setVPList( event.currentTarget.selectedItem )"/>
                </s:FormItem>
                <s:FormItem>
                    <s:HGroup width="200">
                        <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>
                        <s:Button label="Cancel" click="pm.quit()"/>
                        <s:Button label="Login" click="{pm.login( tx_username.text, tx_password.text, cb_schoollist.selectedItem.Name );}"/>
                    </s:HGroup>
                </s:FormItem>
            </s:Form>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" paddingLeft="40" paddingBottom="20">
            <view:Icon/>
            <s:VGroup filters="{[ new DropShadowFilter() ]}" gap="0">
                <mx:Spacer height="10"/>
                <s:Label text="GUHSD" color="#ffffff" fontSize="30"/>
                <s:Label text="Academic Referrals" color="#ffffff" fontSize="25"/>
            </s:VGroup>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:VGroup>

</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it working without using Injection?

I dont know if it is related, but we solved a similar issue in previous version doing something like that:

combobox.dataProvider = Model.getInstance().data;
combobox.dropdown.dataProvider = Model.getInstance().data;

Its a workaround for Combobox in SDK 3.5 , but it maybe is a similar issue.

Comment: Well I fixed it but never really figured out what the issue is. The view is in the main app view but then after creationComplete I was creating a new spark Window. Once I stopped adding it to a new AIR Window and just leave the long view in the main WindowedApplication then the issue goes away.